# can you use jquerymobile and jquery at the same time in the same functions?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use jquerymobile.js and jquery.js at the same time?

I have attached the .js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

although it seems to not work correctly. I literally have no jquerymobile code its all just jquery at the moment so just the introduction of jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js breaks everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquerymobile uses jquery... so that should be okay...

what you should look out for is the version...

example, `jQuery Mobile 1.3 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer.`